# Working with a number of variables at a time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have these 10 variables already declared and they each contain a float value.

Is there any way to apply the function `toFixed(prec)` with `prec` as the parameter to all these variables with a shorter code? Using an array or something like that?

```js
x1 = x1.toFixed(prec);
x2 = x2.toFixed(prec);
y1 = y1.toFixed(prec);
y2 = y2.toFixed(prec);
a1 = a1.toFixed(prec);
a2 = a2.toFixed(prec);
b1 = b1.toFixed(prec);
b2 = b2.toFixed(prec);
c1 = c1.toFixed(prec);
c2 = c2.toFixed(prec);
```

Comment: Sure, put them in an array loop over it, but note that you will then need to amend your logic to work with the array (which would most likely be better than N separate variables anyway). Also note that `toFixed()` returns a string, so if you're expecting the returned values to still be Numbers, be aware of that when you perform any operations on them.

Comment: Alternatively, where are you setting these variables originally? If they come from a single source (or small number of sources), you could do the conversion there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the variables into an array, map it and destructure:

```
[x1, x2, y1, y2, ...] = [x1, x2, y1, y2, ...].map(num => num.toFixed(prec));
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should keep all these parameters in object (as associative array in other language), than you can simply loop that object.

```js
/**
Replace this:
x1=x1.toFixed(prec);
x2=x2.toFixed(prec);
y1=y1.toFixed(prec);
y2=y2.toFixed(prec);
a1=a1.toFixed(prec);
a2=a2.toFixed(prec);
b1=b1.toFixed(prec);
b2=b2.toFixed(prec);
c1=c1.toFixed(prec);
c2=c2.toFixed(prec);

with this:
*/

let options = {
  x1: 1.0,
  x2: 2.0,
  x3: 3.0,
}

console.log('Before', options);

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(options)) {
  options[key] = value.toFixed(3);
}

console.log('After', options);
```